# Changing rank across time in R as opposed to by group

Tags: r, ranking

I am having an issue in R where I want to add a rank (or Index) column, though as opposed to the rankings changing every time the combination changes. I want it to change every time the previous combination changes. I will illustrate what I mean  in the code below.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             group = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3),
             rank1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3),
             rank2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4))
```

In the example I am ranking by group. rank1 is consistent with what I have been able do so far, which is at time 4 the rank is 1 because there was a previous instance of that group. I want something similar to rank2, because it accounts for there being a gap between the group == 1 instances, and assigns a different rank accordingly (i.e. at time 4 in rank2 is 3 as opposed to 1).

Comment: Sounds like an `?rle` problem. `rep(seq_along((r <- rle(df$group))$values), r$lengths)` The `data.table` package also has an `rleid` function which will make this a bit quicker.

Comment: Thanks! That gave me exactly what I needed.